# Wired connected but internet not working

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, ethernet

*Edit*-

I forgot to tell that my notebook does not have an inbuilt ethernet port and I use a TP Link UE300 Ethernet adapter to connect to Ethernet. The adapter has plug and play support for Linux and works perfectly fine in Windows (also used to work in Ubuntu a month back) but now not working in Ubuntu. Also, I think this is some driver issue (not sure though).

**lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2357:0601  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3526 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:5a07 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 03f0:0941 Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Could not find any help in similar previously asked questions so asking here.
I work on Ubuntu 18.04 dual-booted with Windows 10. I am having trouble connecting to internet via ethernet. Wifi is working fine. The same LAN connection works perfectly when using Windows.

Attaching outputs of some commands I found on similar threads-

**ifconfig**

```
enx503eaa292ae3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::5cb1:ab0:a367:974c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 50:3e:aa:29:2a:e3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 293234  bytes 27837628 (27.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 107  bytes 14754 (14.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 9253  bytes 771757 (771.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9253  bytes 771757 (771.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1e.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:1e.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO SPI Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
```

**route -n**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
```

**\etc\NetworkManager\NetworkManager.conf**

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does Ethernet work on Windows? I don't see any Ethernet adapter in `lspci`. maybe it is disabled in BIOS.

Comment: Yes it works with windows

Comment: You need to find out what kind of Ethernet adapter is installed.

Comment: Name [00000009] Realtek 8822BE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC
Adapter Type Ethernet 802.3
Product Type Realtek 8822BE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC
I got this when I searched for network adapter using Windows.

Comment: This is the wireless adapter, not the wired.

Comment: Okay sorry I am new to all this. I actually have an ASUS notebook which does not have a built in Ethernet port. I use TP Link U300 3.0 ethernet adapter for accessing LAN. It works fine in windows and also used to work in Ubuntu until a month back.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @grv You should have started with that you are using the dongle. The question was very unclear.

Comment: Sorry for that, I have edited my question accordingly.